# itertools.accumulate but trying to replace lambda with str.join

Tags: python

I'm trying not to use lambda here because of it's performance issues in loops, I know there's uses for lambda but I find this one should have a better alternative.

Original code: *this works but I don't like that lambda there.*

```
from itertools import accumulate

s = "lorem ipsum dolor"

print(list(accumulate(s.split(), lambda x, y: f'{x} {y}')))
#["lorem", "lorem ipsum", "lorem ipsum dolor"]
```

I have tried the following:

```
print(list(accumulate(s.split(), ' '.join)))
```

I must be missing something small here that will make me feel like an idiot. It has to be just a simple matter of packing the tuple I assume.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `str.join` method expects an iterable as an argument, and yet `accumulate` passes to it two arguments for each iteration, hence the error. You can use the `str.format` method instead:

```
print(list(accumulate(s.split(), '{} {}'.format)))
```